# How to check whether a javascript object contains any values while having keys

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object which contains error messages:

```
err: {
  subject: '',
  body: '',
  recipient: ''
},
```

i want to disable a submit button based on whether an error is present. in the above declaration, there are no errors present.

i'm aware of `Object.values(err)` but i do not know how to use the resulting list, which has a length of 3.

how would I do this? thank you

Comment: What did you try? in any case, you may want to use `Object.values(err).some(e => e !== '' && e !== null && e !== undefined);` or something like that. if Object.values is not support, just revert to object.keys: `Object.keys(err).some(e => err[e] !== null && err[e] !== undefined && err[e] !== '');` (assuming the error is present whenever any key is defined and not empty).

Comment: i wasn't aware of .some(), that should work. thank you very much

Comment: remember to include the polyfill, since it's not a standard of **every browser**, so you might encounter some browser not having the correct ES version to use it.

Comment: lol, didn't know what a polyfill was, thanks a ton for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.some()` on the `Object.values()` to check if there are some error messages

```js
let obj = {
  err: {
    subject: '',
    body: '',
    recipient: ''
  }
};

let someErrors = Object.values(obj.err).some(e => e.length);
console.log(someErrors);
```

Answer (score 1):

> const obj = {name: "Naimur", age: 21}
>
> console.log("name" in obj) => true
>
> console.log("age" in obj) => true
>
> console.log("location" in obj) => false

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var data={
  err: {
    subject: '',
    body: '',
    recipient: ''
  },
};

if(data.err.subject!='' || data.err.body!='' || data.err.recipient!=''){
 console.log('ERROR!');
}else{
 console.log('ALL RIGHT!');
}
```

Comment: this was my solution at first, but i thought there should be a better method

Answer (score 0):

```
var err =  {
  subject: 'some error',
  body: 'message',
  recipient: 'Tom'
};
```

`Object.values(err)` will return an array `Array ["some error", 'message', 'Tom']`. Now, you can check the values of this array and then disable the button if these values satisfy some conditions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that all of the elements have to equal '' for there to be a valid error. So you can use the `.every()` method to check every element in the returned array. If only some of the elements have to equal '' for there to be an error message, just user `.some()` instead.

```
let err = {
  subject: '',
  body: '',
  recipient: ''
}

console.log(!Object.values(err).every(e => e === '')) //returns false meaning there isn't an error message
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use .reduce() to return the sum of errors and also check if err has values with this code

```
if( (Object.values(err).length) ? Object.values(err).reduce((ac, next) => ac + next.length, 0) :false ){
  console.log( 'there is errors' );   
}
```

Comment: In this example is there a time when `Object.values(err).length` will return anything but 3? Assuming of course you don't delete keys/values or add more?

Comment: @Matt im asuming this should work with any amount of keys an also not pass the if statement if err is empty {}